# Redirect entire website to a new website's homepage in php

Tags: php, redirect

Can anyone help me how to write a redirect in php. I want to redirect a website and all of it's pages to a new website's homepage. From the old website I don't want to redirect the (`www.oldwebsite.com/administrator/`) page.

My old redirect was:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.newwebsite.ro");
?>
```

This was not good because when I clicked on (`www.oldwebsite.com/a/b`) it redirected me to (`www.newwebsite.ro/404error`) and I didn't want that.

How should I do it right?

Answer (score 0):

You should use die() or exit() after header

```
header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use htaccess to redirect from old domain to new. Here is example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: in htaccess I used this : RewriteEngine On

#redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator/
RewriteRule (.*) https://newsitero/$1 [R=301,L]
 but nothing happened and that's why I made a php redirect

Comment: Did you try example from my answer  ?

Comment: If pages have the same url then do the following 

header("Location: http://example.com/" . $pathTopage);
die();

So when somebody visits your page on old site they will be redirected to new site with same url.

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I don't know why I can't redirect in any way. Not even in php. Thank you in advance.